# can not stop interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have a state that updates the time every second with setTimeout, but I can not clear it with ClearTimeout. When I print timerClear value, it shows me different values.

```
var timerClear ;

const [MyTime, setMyTime] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  timerClear = setInterval(() => {
     setMyTime(
       realeTime.toLocaleTimeString([], {
       timeZone: "Asia/Tehran",
       hour: '2-digit',
       minute: '2-digit',
       second: '2-digit',
       hour12: false,
       }),
     );

     checkTime();

  }, 1000);
}, [MyTime]);
```

In the check function, if the time reaches the desired value, I clear all the timers

```
if (filterGetTime > filterEndTime) {
   if (data.examParents[0].examParent_method == "0") { 
      console.log('timerClear',timerClear);
                    
      alert('زمان امتحان تمام شده است!!!');
      if(sendReqDelay){
         clearTimeout(sendReqDelay);
      }
      clearTimeout(setTimeToPageTimeOut);
      clearTimeout(TimerIntervalSolveQuestions);
      clearInterval(timerClear);
   } 
             
}
```

After each confirmation of the button in Alert

```
alert('زمان امتحان تمام شده است!!!');
```

```
console.log('timerClear',timerClear);
```

Prints another number.

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom hook?

Comment: every time `MyTime` changes you're creating a new interval and overriding `timerClear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the dependency array `[MyTime]` every time `MyTime` changes, you're creating a new interval and the reference to old interval is lost. With such setup you're better off using a `setTimeout`.

Also since you have a normal variable, it is redeclared on every re-render.
If you're going to use `setInterval` you should be using a `useRef` to keep reference to it and remove `MyTime` from dependency array.

---

Something along the lines of:

```
const timerClear = useRef() ;
const [myTime, setMyTime] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  timerClear.current = setInterval(() => {
     setMyTime(
        // ...
     );
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(timeClear.current);
}, []);
```